# Transition for grouped bar chart in d3 when updating the data values

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I made a grouped bar chart using d3.js. The data comes from a file named "data.csv". I then added an event listener  to update the data in the graph on click, using another csv file "data-column.csv". This part seems to work fine.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
 drawGraph(data, false);
});

d3.select("#similar").on("click", function() {
 d3.csv("data-column.csv", function(error, data) {
  drawGraph(data, true);
 });
});
```

Now, and this is where my question comes in, I need to add a transition between these changes in value. I already added a transition line but it doesn't seem to work (I have to admit I am new to d3 and I guess I am lacking some basic understanding of how the data is handled in the code) .

The transition method is part of the drawGraph(data,update) function :

```
 function drawGraph(data, update) {
  var genderNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Category"; }); // get list of column variables : age ranges

  data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.genders = genderNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; }); // get the name of each category filter and its value
  });


  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Category; })); // state names in X axis
  x1.domain(genderNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]); // set separation settings between x values
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.genders, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]); // ages in y axis

  /* X axis */
  svg.select(".x.axis").remove();

  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(xAxis);

  /* Y axis */
  svg.select(".y.axis").remove();
  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(yAxis)

  // Y axis title
  .append("text") 
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("y", 6)
   .attr("dy", ".71em")
   .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .text("Percentage of Calls");

  /* data */

  var category = svg.selectAll(".category")
   .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "g")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Category) + ",0)"; });

  /* rectangles */  
  var rects = category.selectAll("rect")
   .data(function(d) { return d.genders; });

  if (update) {
   svg.selectAll("rect").remove();
   rects.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
    rects.exit().remove();
    rects
    .transition().duration(750)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
  } else {
  rects.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
    rects.exit().remove();
 } 
}
```

The if (update) { } else { } is triggered with the onclick event listener stated above.

I added this remove( ) method because when I call the new values, they come on top of the first ones like a stacked bar..

```
if (update) {
   svg.selectAll("rect").remove();
```

For more details, here is my entire html/css/js file on this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/safanobu/o36dk8go/) link. It's not working though since I couldn't attach the CSVs

below is my initial CSV file "data.csv":

```
Category,women,men
Work environment,71.94,28.06
rehab chain,71.22,28.78 
D. employment%,70.93,29.07
Studies,70.44,29.56
Rehabilitation,68.13,31.87
Coaching,66.35,33.65
Salary counseling,62.23,37.77
Travel Agreement,37.74,62.26
Discharge,36.91,63.09
Competition,27.10,72.90
```

and here is the CSV with updated values "data-column.csv":

```
Category,women,men
Work environment, 2.92, 1.47
rehab chain, 0.15, 0.29
D. employment%, 0.05, 0.09
Studies, 0.84, 1.55
Rehabilitation, 0.58, 0.96
Coaching, 0.07, 0.10
Salary counseling, 5.92, 7.52
Travel Agreement, 0.12, 0.06
Discharge, 0.27, 0.12
Competition, 1.00, 0.29
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should contain a transition between start to end:

```
rects.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", 0) //start width
        .attr("height", 0) //start height
        ......
        .transition().duration(750)
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); }) //end height
            .attr("width", x1.rangeBand()); //end width
```

hope it helps!

see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWivujuOirco5Y64BZUd?p=preview)